# Command Button to Open A <p:dialog> From a Different xhtml file

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces, facelets, primefaces

In a JSF 2.0 application with richfaces and primefaces, I would like a command button when clicked to open a  however the dialog is in another xhtml file. How can I achieve this in either primefaces or richfaces.

I have tried

```
<a4j:commandButton value="Search" id="buttonQuickSearch" action="#{customerDetailsBean.quickSearch}" oncomplete="quickview.dlg.show();"/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `<ui:include>` to include the dialog code in the master page.

```
<ui:include src="dialog.xhtml" />
```